# How do you apply a transform to a UILabel before animating in Swift?

Tags: swift, rotation, uilabel, transform

I'd like to have a view rotated without animating before the view animates a scale. The way I have it now ignores my initial view rotation if I have the animation afterwards.

```
label.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(90.0 * .pi / 180))

animateLabel(label:label)

func animateLabel(label:UILabel) {

    label.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.6, y: 0.6)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        label.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.1, y: 1.1)
    },
    completion: { _ in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
            label.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)

        }
    })

}
```

**Update**: How I updated my code with Matt's answer so it animates correctly:

I first setup the initial rotation as a transform variable, then send that when I call animateLabel:

```
var transforms: CGAffineTransform = .identity

transforms = transforms.concatenating(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(90.0 * .pi / 180)))

animateLabel(label:label, transforms:transforms)
```

I concat the scale and set the transform to the modified transform. Then I can use scale by for the actual animations:

```
func animateLabel(label:UILabel, transforms:CGAffineTransform) {

    transforms.concatenating(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.6, y: 0.6))

    label.transform = transforms

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        label.transform = transforms.scaledBy(x: 1.1, y: 1.1)
    },
    completion: { _ in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
            label.transform = transforms.scaledBy(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: Yes because you're applying a new transform at the beginning of your animateLabel function.

Comment: I see that, but how to make that rotation permanent? I even tried redefining the identity.

Comment: You need to create new transforms that combine the rotation and the scale. You could look at `CGAffineTransform.scaledBy` to modify the existing transform, or `CGAffineTransform.concatenating` to combine 2 transforms.

Comment: Actually scaleBy doesn't animate the view. Never mind

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The way I have it now ignores my initial view rotation if I have the animation afterwards.

It’s easy to see why. A view has just one transform. Your second transform *replaces* the first:

```
label.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(90.0 * .pi / 180))
label.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.6, y: 0.6)
```

That is what you are doing. Instead you need to *apply* the second transform *to* the first. Look at methods that combine a second transform with the first, instead of replacing the first entirely. For example https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgaffinetransform/1455882-scaledby

Thus I was easily able to get this, which seems to be a rough approximation of what you want:

[image]

To get that, I prepared two transforms, the rotation, plus the rotation-plus-scale:

```
    let rot = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(90.0 * .pi / 180))
    let scale = rot.scaledBy(x: 1.5, y: 1.5)
```

Comment: Yes I’m telling  you why what you have right now is wrong!

Comment: I've never really understood the Apple documentation.

Comment: Would you mind posting an answer instead of linking to the documentation? I understand what I did doesn't work, but I still don't understand how to make this work, or find any examples. Using scaleBy also doesn't animate the view.

Comment: I’d need a better description of the effect you are trying to achieve. Is it that the view should jump to a rotated angle, then waggle its scale with animation, and then remain rotated?

Comment: Hi Matt, yes exactly - The view should already be rotated then animate the scale with the same rotation.

Comment: Added a demonstration.

Comment: Thanks. I'll edit my answer how I integrated that into my animation.